# How to use an <h2> tag </h2> inside a <p></p> in the middle of a text?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, text

I want to do something like this:

```
<p>This is a <h2>text</h2> paragraph.</p>
```

I disabled margin and padding for the h2 but it still breaks the line before and after the h2 tag. How can I use the h2 tag in the middle of a text and make it look like if it was a normal word, just like < b > does?

The doctype of my html document is "XHTML 1.0 Transitional"

Comment: That's not valid XHTML. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually, the css tag display:block tag is more suitable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not appropriate to use a tag that means "heading" within body text. The `<h..>` tags are logical tags; their use imparts *meaning* to the enclosed text -- namely, that the text is a section heading.

Although you could use the `display: inline` attribute, consider using a more appropriate tag, or even a `<span>` tag.

Comment: What if you place it at the beginning of the paragraph as a subheading? Would it still be better to use a <span> tag? Example: <h1>Chapter 1<h2> <p><h2>Part I.</h2> text text text text text</p>

Comment: @AlexWilliams I know this was a while ago, but I think the proper use would be `<h1>Chapter 1</h1><h2>Part I</h2><p>text...</p>` in this case.

Comment: You can't use `display: inline`. The h2 element will implicitly terminate the p element.

Answer (score 30):

It is not valid to have a `h2` inside of a `p`.

Aside from that, and to answer your question, a `h2` is a `block` level element. Making it an `inline` level element will cause it to behave similarly to how you describe the `b` tag acting.

```
p h2{display:inline}
```

As I said above though, the HTML you've given is invalid.

Comment: Can I upvote this again?

Comment: +1 For stressing using valid code.

Answer (score 3):

Don't, the whole point of  is that it's a header. Headers are on their own line.  Instead, use CSS.  Say text and then in a CSS file, choose a font size.

Comment: I’m gonna be a bit to close on the words here, but the h stands for headline, not header. Header is something different and headlines are in wider use (not just as a header). Anyway, don’t take this comment to serious … One could say every headline is a header for something. But when I hear header I’m thinking about a website header, more of a layout element.

Comment: Yeah sorry, you're technically right.

Comment: @Kissaki: [From the horse's mouth](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.5), they're called headings. I'm even more pedantic! :P

Answer (score 1):

You’ll have to make it

```
display:inline;
```

h2 is a block element.

The h2 tag marks a headline, which is per definition not part of a text. So what you’re doing is probably not the best way. Consider doing it differently.

Comment: It's not only not the best way, but it's completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Despite of the wrong use of the `<h2>` tag inside a paragraph, we can style `<h2>` to keep him into a paragraph. I tested one of the above css trick in Firefox and Chrome as follow:

HTML code `<p>One paragraph with <h2>title text</h2> in the middle</p>`

CSS trick `p h2{display:inline}`

BUT it doesn't get the result I expect. The browser truncate the paragraph right before the initial h2 tag. Look at DOM from Firebug:

[image]

Therefore the CSS trick `p h2{display:inline}` doesn't work properly because CSS rule is not true, i.e. the `<h2>` tag is not inside the `<p>` tag. It looks like this:

[image]

Adding CSS trick only for `<h2>` tag `h2{display:inline}` is not the definitive solution. It will look like this:

[image]

The final work-around is:

HTML code `<p class="inline-object">One paragraph with <h2 class="inline-object">title text</h2> in the middle</p>`

CSS trick `.inline-object" {display:inline}`

This will look as we expect:

[image]

If you are trying to mask `<h2>` title text as ordinary text, just add two more rules to the class `.inline-object" {display:inline;font-size: inherit;font-weight: normal;}`

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like .myH2 (not the best name) with same code of h2 and use a span in p like

```
<p>this is <span class="myH2">myH2</span>.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox cutting out my P, because of H2 inside it. And then creating P for

(empty paragraph). And its good. Because its auto-generated, and for cleaning out P tags i need to write tens of PHP code.