# Is this usage of the H2 tag correct?

Tags: html

I use the h2 tag in this way. Is this usage of the H2 tag correct?

```
<h2><a href="#w" style="margin-left:20px;">What is this?</a></h2>
<h2><a href="#h" style="margin-left:20px;">How much does it cost?</a></h2>


<p class="title-faq"><h2>What is this?</h2></p>
```

Comment: i'd say the first two are ok but the third one you shouldn't really put an h2 inside a p

Answer (score 2):

It's not appropriate to use a tag that means "heading" within body text. The  tags are logical tags; their use imparts meaning to the enclosed text -- namely, that the text is a section heading.

Although you could use the display: inline attribute, consider using a more appropriate tag, or even a  tag.

Aside from that, and to answer your question, a h2 is a block level element. Making it an inline level element will cause it to behave similarly to how you describe the b tag acting

[**SEE HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675985/how-to-use-an-h2-tag-h2-inside-a-p-p-in-the-middle-of-a-text)

Answer (score 0):

The first two are ok, you put the H2 tag outside the A tag. However, the P tag denotes an paragraph of text, so you should put your header tag before this P tag.

Answer (score 0):

No. When you have two headings of the same level in succession, what would the first one be a heading for?

Using a link inside a heading is technically allowed, but poor usability. Headings are normally targets for links, instead of being clickable.

Nesting `h2` inside `p` is not even syntactically valid, or possible: a browser implies a closing `</p>` when a `p` element is open and an `<h2>` tag is encountered.

It’s also bad for maintainability and modifiability to use inline styles (like here in `style` attribuets).