# p tag as parent is getting weird

Tags: html, css

I am using p tag as parent and adding few elements in it. But the problem is, when you look at inspect code p tag is displaying individually and it is not holding the childs inside.

Her is the html

```
<div class="createapp_div">
                 <p><h1>Select</h1> <button class=""></button> <button class=""></button></p>
                 <p><span>Name</span> <input type="text" /></p>
                <button>Create</button>
            </div>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Zdr4U/)**

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675985/how-to-use-an-h2-tag-h2-inside-a-p-p-in-the-middle-of-a-text) for reference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Explanation

The `p` DOM Element can only contain **inline** elements. ([*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)) ([*W3C HTML5*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element))

> The start tag is mandatory. The end tag may be omitted if the `<p>` element is immediately followed by an `<address>`, `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<blockquote>`, `<div>`, `<dl>`, `<fieldset>`, `<footer>`, `<form>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, `<h6>`, `<header>`, `<hr>`, `<menu>`, `<nav>`, `<ol>`, `<pre>`, `<section>`, `<table>`, `<ul>` or another `<p>` element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an `<a>` element.

---

### Permitted tags

Here is an [**exhaustive list**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) of the **permitted tags** inside a `p` element.

Content:

`<abbr>, <audio>, <b>, <bdo>, <br>, <button>, <canvas>, <cite>, <code>, <command>, <datalist>, <dfn>, <em>, <embed>, <i>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <kbd>, <keygen>, <label>, <mark>, <math>, <meter>, <noscript>, <object>, <output>, <progress>, <q>, <ruby>, <samp>, <script>, <select>, <small>, <span>, <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <svg>, <textarea>, <time>, <var>, <video>, <wbr>` **and plain text** (not only consisting of white spaces characters).

Comment: @SebastianG You are right. Thank you for telling me; it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't place headers inside a `<p>` element.