# Configuration to allow lists to be wrapped inside paragraphs

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I am using tinymce 3.5.5 . I have the following configuration of valid_elements/valid_children

```
valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style|onmouseover]," +
"a[name|href|target|title|alt]," +
"#p,blockquote,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src|height|width],-sub,-sup,-b,-i,-u," +
"-span[data-mce-type],hr",

valid_children: "body[p|ol|ul]" +
",p[a|span|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|hr|#text]" +
",span[p|a|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|#text]" +
",a[span|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|#text]" +
",b[span|a|i|u|sup|sub|img|#text]" +
",i[span|a|b|u|sup|sub|img|#text]" +
",sup[span|a|i|b|u|sub|img|#text]" +
",sub[span|a|i|b|u|sup|img|#text]" +
",li[span|a|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|ol|ul|#text]" +
",ol[li]" +
",ul[li]",
```

Content of my textarea before editor init:

```
<textarea name="content">
    <p>
      <ul>
        <li>list_elem</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
</textarea>
```

Content after editor init:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
  <ul>
    <li>list_elem</li>
  </ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Tinymce removes the list from the paragraph even though the configuration should render this valid.

I created a tinymce fiddle for this: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/7ndaab/3
Any help is appreciated.

**What do i need to define/set in order to allow lists as children of paragraphs?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [p tag as parent is getting weird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319470/p-tag-as-parent-is-getting-weird)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

You **can't**. Your browser won't let you do it. You would need to edit the browser behaviors and standards. The best solution would be to fork Chromium and adjust it to your needs.

### Explanation

The `p` DOM Element can only contain **inline** elements. ([*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)) ([*W3C HTML5*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element))

> The start tag is mandatory. The end tag may be omitted if the `<p>` element is immediately followed by an `<address>`, `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<blockquote>`, `<div>`, `<dl>`, `<fieldset>`, `<footer>`, `<form>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, `<h6>`, `<header>`, `<hr>`, `<menu>`, `<nav>`, `<ol>`, `<pre>`, `<section>`, `<table>`, `<ul>` or another `<p>` element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an `<a>` element.

---

### Permitted tags

Here is an [**exhaustive list**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) of the **permitted tags** inside a `p` element.

Content:

`<abbr>, <audio>, <b>, <bdo>, <br>, <button>, <canvas>, <cite>, <code>, <command>, <datalist>, <dfn>, <em>, <embed>, <i>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <kbd>, <keygen>, <label>, <mark>, <math>, <meter>, <noscript>, <object>, <output>, <progress>, <q>, <ruby>, <samp>, <script>, <select>, <small>, <span>, <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <svg>, <textarea>, <time>, <var>, <video>, <wbr>` **and plain text** (not only consisting of white spaces characters).

Comment: +1 Well, hmm i thought i could tweak the tinymce config in order to reach the target. Didn't come to my mind that the browser wouldn't let me.

Comment: @Thariama You'll probably make `TinyMCE` act the way you want it to do, but you'll never see it in your browser like it should be, because if TinyMCE sends `<p><ul></ul></p>` to any popular browser, it'll interpret it as `<p></p><ul></ul><p></p>`. (I know it sucks... You might want to give a try to other elements such as a `div` or a similar container element?)

Comment: A div with a list would be valid i think. Problem is can't just switch from paragraphs to divs because of my own complex plugins that only handles paragraphs

Comment: @Thariama I will come back to you if I find some kind of alternative.

Comment: that would be very kind. Thanks so far.