# set space between html5 elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple html file with 2 column like structure. I managed it but there is no space between each element as you can see in the JSFiddled demo. I tried margin and padding but failed. How can I put some space between input elements for example?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PY374/1/)

And here is my css:

```
    .left
    {
    position:relative;
    left:10px;      
    }

    .right
    {
    position:fixed;
    left:300px;   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use [`p` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html) to surround your label-field matches instead of using [`br`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/br.html) line breaks, and would still be valid HTML.

For example:

```
<p>
    <label for="foo">Foo:</label>
    <textarea id="foo"></textarea>
</p>
```

Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PY374/4/).

Comment: Although this answer is valid, I would like to remind people that you should not fix all your problems using the `p` tag, as [some tags will just break the `p` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17319496/1451422).

Comment: @JeffNoel Interesting, I did have some problems with the `p` tag in the past. Most modern browsers overlook it though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `inline-block` for this type of thing:

```
.left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 0.6em;
}
label, input, select {
    margin: 0.5em 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but buttons on the left widened this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but why are you using relative label and fix position for inputs?

```
.left {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to achieve that view where labels on the left input elements on the right where they are on the same line. I didnt know any other way to get that view.

Answer (score 0):

.left
        {
            position:relative;
            left:10px;
            width:300px;
            float:left;
            display:block;
        }

```
    .right
    {
        position:relative;
        left:0px;
        display:block;
    }
```

This works fine with your jsfiddle. Tested it there. Add further margins if you need. The display:block does the trick

Comment: Thank you for the answer but buttons on the left widens this way.@MichalVoják s answer is better for me.