# My p tag is not doing its job

Tags: html

Let's cut to the chase. This is the piece of code that is giving me trouble:

```
<p id="mainBlock">
    <img src="/icons/128x128.png" id="icon">
    <h3>App name</h3>
    <span id="version"></span>
</p>
<p>Description</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/0pd7njbr/

Looks okay to me. But when I try it in Chrome, this is what I see in the console:

[image]

This is not the correct markup! Notice the `<p>` is messed up. I have been looking at this for a while now and still can't see what's causing that.

<sub>I can't believe I made a question asking why my `p` tags are not working.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`p` elements may not contain headings, including `h3` elements.

The end tag for `p` elements is optional, so the `p` element is implicitly ended by the `h3` start tag.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have pulling my hair out but I never realized that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Its not appropriate to add a heading tag within a p tag that is probably why you are getting that problem. Look here: [How to use an <h2> tag </h2> inside a <p></p> in the middle of a text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675985/how-to-use-an-h2-tag-h2-inside-a-p-p-in-the-middle-of-a-text)