# issue with css flex, specific div that is no different than others will not accept a class

Tags: html, css

here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/aronlilland/e9wk8n2r/

i have 9 divs with a class of .box with several child divs inside each, my issue is that one or two divs don't recognize the classes that i assign to them, they are no different than the others. so it just makes no sense to me...

if you expand the fiddle window as long as it goes to get the columns to display more than one you will notice 3 of the divs dont adjust with the rest

html

```
  <div id="wrapper">
<div class="box box1">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="http://www.moorelife.org/freedownloads-serieslist.php?" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/resources/keith_moore.jpg" alt="keith moore" class="resource_image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p><h2>Keith Moore</h2>
      Teacher/Pastor, I reffer to Keith as my "bible college experience,"
      he has 30+ years of free audio and video available on any and every
      subject.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box box2">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIXcY2izjpDgROo3MRlAU2MJSyjthXLLc" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/resources/kenneth_hagin.jpg" alt="kenneth hagin" class="resource_image">
    </a>
</div>
  <div class="text">
    <p><h2>Kenneth Hagin</h2>
      Prophet, with nearly 70 years of ministry under his belt, Hagin most
      commonly preached on the subject of faith in Gods word.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box box3">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEtP4XPKdli585uNfIU8WNRYawCusmEYK" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/resources/bill_johnson.jpg" alt="bill johnson" class="resource_image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p><h2>Bill Johnson</h2>
      Apostle/Pastor, Bill pastors a church in Redding California named
      Bethel Church, the church is most known for miracles, signs and
      wonders.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box box4">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/ToddWhiteChannel/videos" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/resources/todd_white.jpg" alt="todd white" class="resource_image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p><h2>Todd White</h2>
      Evangelist, Todd takes love on the streets and
      preaches the gospel with radical miracles taking place everywhere he
      goes.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box box5">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/results?filters=video&lclk=video&search_query=terry+mize" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/resources/terry_mize.jpg" alt="terry mize" class="resource_image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p><h2>Terry Mize</h2>
      Apostle, Terry ministers around the world in
      third world countries preaching mainly on the authority of the
      believer & the power of Gods word.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box box6">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSL2kAQNbd_CCw9ElCcp2hPd0itjqj7N0" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/resources/kenneth_copeland.jpg" alt="kenneth copeland" class="resource_image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p><h2>Kenneth Copeland</h2>
      Prophet, Kenneth has impacted my life greatly
      by teaching me how to obey Gods word and live by faith, I have seen the
      good fruit year after year.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box box7">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLolQwmvb1tjoFSsW55OSDyl-ax_gtVQJR" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/resources/reinhard_bonnke.jpg" alt="reinhard bonnke" class="resource_image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p><h2>Reinhard Bonnke</h2>
      Evangelist, Reinhard is probably the most
      power packed evangelist in our generation. His ministy CFAN has
      reached over 70 million new converts for Jesus.</p>
  </div>
<div class="box box8">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlqtIWnWpiB_7aWRtZTIMGWsN1K91f8JH" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/resources/norvel_hayes.jpg" alt="norvel hayes" class="resource_image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p><h2>Norvel Hayes</h2>
    Teacher, Norvel is a general of the faith, Norvel Hayes has been
    ministering on the subject of faith in Gods word and worship for over
    50 years.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box box9">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/results?lclk=playlist&search_query=john+wimber&filters=playlist" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/resources/john_wimber.jpg" alt="john wimber" class="resource_image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p><h2>John Wimber</h2>
    Pastor, John was a local Anaheim pastor with a worldwide impact, he is
    founder of the Vineyard and taught often on spiritual gifts.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please detail exactly what you are expecting to be rendered here and how it differs from your fiddle?

Comment: also add your css code to

Comment: box5 n box7 doesnot have background colour as other boxes have

Comment: i need every div with the class of .box to be fluid on resize, when the screen is large enough for the divs to not be in a single column there are three divs on the bottom that are sitting completely outside of the other columns

Comment: not sure if it's relevant but you may want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675985/how-to-use-an-h2-tag-h2-inside-a-p-p-in-the-middle-of-a-text

Comment: This is a good tool for checking for errors in your HTML: https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you doesn't have `</div>` of `box7`

Close one div before `<div class="box box8">`

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e9wk8n2r/1/)**

Comment: you rock, iv been staring at this thing for an hour.

Comment: @AronLilland Glad to help you.