# I'd like to change the content of the <p></p> element by using javascript code but it dosen't work

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'd like to change the content of the p element:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-avatar">
        <h4>{{name}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-body">
        <p id='output1'>
          <h4>welcome to ionic</h4>
          x
        </p>
      </div>
```

so I'm trying this javascript code:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var output1 = document.getElementById('output1');
        output1.innerHTML = data[id].when;
      </script>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use an <h2> tag </h2> inside a <p></p> in the middle of a text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675985/how-to-use-an-h2-tag-h2-inside-a-p-p-in-the-middle-of-a-text)

Comment: how does this not work. What is the output you are expecting and what is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried it in Chrome, it worked to some degree. But as the linked questions below point out, the behavior can differ between browsers. This is my rendered html:

```
<div class="item item-body">
  <p id="output1">data[id].when</p>
  <h4>welcome to ionic</h4>
  x
  <p></p>
</div>
```

As you can see, your `output1` `p` was broken into two. This happens if you use elements like `h4` inside `p` elements. The heading breaks the paragraph into: `p`, `h4`, `x`, and another `p`. The first `p` is the one you defined, and its inner html is correctly replaced (well, it is empty initially, so it is just added). The result is that it looks like you just **add** the inner html instead of **replacing** it.

In order to fix it, you could use `display: inline-block` or (better) replace your `p` by a more appropriate element.

Please, read these questions for more information:

[How to use an <h2> tag </h2> inside a <p></p> in the middle of a text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675985/how-to-use-an-h2-tag-h2-inside-a-p-p-in-the-middle-of-a-text)

[Nesting block level elements inside the <p> tag... right or wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

> you can try out this

```
 <ion-view>
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-avatar">
         <h4>{{name}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-body">
       <p ng-bind-html="Mycontent">
       </p>
   </div> 
 </ion-content>
```

> in Controller

```
$scope.Mycontent="<h4>welcome to ionic</h4> x";
```

> this will print all html code into p tag as it is.
>
> in final your javascript code wiil be like that

```
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.Mycontent=data[id].when;
  });
```