# Conditional Js for Wordpress website doesn't work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, error-handling, conditional-statements, multilingual

I am working on a multilingual website on wordpress.

I need to have different taglines on the french side and on the English side.

In html for menu header I have both taglines :

```
<p id='conditional'><h2 style="color: rgb(125, 119, 119); font-family: 'Courgette', cursive; margin-top: 20px;">Écouter, observer, questionner pour se rencontrer soi-même et rencontrer l'autre</h2></p>
<p id=‘conditional2’><h2 style="color: rgb(125, 119, 119); font-family: 'Courgette', cursive; margin-top: 20px;">to listen and all </h2></p>
```

and in JS i have a condition for printing one tagline only :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("en") > -1) {
                  $('#conditional').css('visibility', 'hidden');
alert("ENGLISH");
}
        else {
                  $('#conditional2’).css('visibility', 'hidden');
alert("FRENCH");
}
    });
</script>
```

In console, i got this error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

on this line

```
$('#conditional2’).css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Can somebody help me, I am just trying to print one tagline or an other if i am on the french side or on the english one.

U can see how is it working on https://isabellemillon-pratique-philosophique.com/en/home/ or https://isabellemillon-pratique-philosophique.com/

Comment: Typo: Replace `’` character with `'` character and try again.

Comment: `$('#conditional2’).css('visibility', 'hidden');` there is quote wrong after `2` start quote is different and ending quote is wrong please correct them and use `'`

Comment: Try this **$('#conditional2').css('visibility', 'hidden');** 
The quotation marks in you script looks incorrect.

Comment: Thanks a lot, there is no more error in console, but the 2 tagline are still printed. Anybody have an idea ??

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Change your paragraph tags to divs and I think you'll be set. Having heading tags inside p tags is not valid. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675985/how-to-use-an-h2-tag-h2-inside-a-p-p-in-the-middle-of-a-text