# Why css is not being applied on the elements with same class?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

<style>
    .city
    {
        background-color: black;
        color:blanchedalmond;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="city">
<h1>Paris</h1>
    </div>
    <p class="city"><h2>Germany</h2></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I was learning about classes and now I made two html elements with the same class but css is not applied on the p tag.

Comment: ```<p><h2 class="city">Germany</h2></p>```, though <p> should not contain a <h2> tag? so just remove the <p> tag and you're all good

Answer (score 5):

Because `p` cannot contain `h2`.

Check your browser's element inspector. The `h2` automatically closes the `p` element, as a result this is the HTML actually being rendered:

```html
<p class="city"></p>
<h2>Germany</h2>
<p></p>
```

```html
<p class="city"></p><!-- the closing tag here is automatically added by the browser because the `<h2>` closes a parent `<p>` element -->
<h2>Germany</h2>
<!--the missing opening tag <p> is added by the browser's fault tolerance here --></p>
```

Comment: Is it a rule that it cannot contain it?

Comment: It is a rule. From the [p element specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element): "A p element's end tag can be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by ... , h2 ...". That is, when the parser finds the `<h2>` tag after an opening `<p>` tag, it considers the `<p>` tag to be closed without the explicit ending tag.

Answer (score 2):

It's about **HTML structure** and **display**:

`<h2>` should not be inside `<p>` (You don't need `<p>` to covert your `<h2>`)

---

**Display:** (style)

`<h2>` is as a **block**

`<p>` is as an **inline**

---

**HTML structure:** (render)

```
<p><h2>Germany</h2></p>
```

will be rendered to:

```
<p class="city"></p>
<h2>Germany</h2>
<p></p>
```

**Trick:**

Right click on that element in your browser and **Inspect** it for see HTML rendered result (very useful for debug)

[image]

**Read more:** [How to use an <h2> tag </h2> inside a <p></p> in the middle of a text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675985/how-to-use-an-h2-tag-h2-inside-a-p-p-in-the-middle-of-a-text)

Comment: `<p>` is a **block level**, not an inline one. Of course, you may change its display type through CSS.

Comment: How can i change

Comment: To be clearer, you may change the `<p>` display type to 'inline', but this would not change the behaviour of `<p>` followed by `<h2>` or other block level elements. If you can, you may use it the other way round: put the `<p>` tag inside the `<h2>` tag, although I would reccomend to use other inline tags for this purpose. The heading tags may be composed with more structured elements. It is not only to indicate that the text is a heading. For example: `<h2>This is an <em>emphasized</em> and <br />two lines <span class"red">red</span> heading</h2>`